# Stored procedure doesnt add new values to the old value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by, sum

I have a table with timereports from users. Now i want all timereports during one week from a specific user will be shown on one row instead of 7 different rows (1 for each day). The Insert statement down below is done 7 times (1 for each day).

If a insertstatements variables (ProjID, ActivityID, TimeCodeID, TimeUnitID and tempUserID matches one specific row in #tempTable should it add the new values (Quant) to the specific row in temptable instead of create a new row in temptable. But if one of the ID's doesnt match should it be a new row.

Here are my code:

```
CREATE PROC getweek2
@UserID nvarchar(50)
, @DateFrom datetime
AS

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
id int primary key identity(1,1)
, ProjID nvarchar(50)
, ActivityID nvarchar(50)
, TimeCodeID nvarchar(50)
, QuantMon decimal(18,2)
, QuantTue decimal(18,2)
, QuantWed decimal(18,2)
, QuantThu decimal(18,2)
, QuantFri decimal(18,2)
, QuantSat decimal(18,2)
, QuantSun decimal(18,2)
, QuantSum decimal(18,2)
, tempUserID nvarchar(50)
, TimeUnitID nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #tempTable 
SELECT 
t.a3CloudTimeProjectID AS ProjID
, t.a3CloudTimeActivityID AS ActivityID
, t.a3CloudTimeCodeID AS TimeCodeID
, SUM(t.a3CloudTimeQuantity) AS QuantMon
, SUM(0) AS QuantTue
, SUM(0) AS QuantWed
, SUM(0) AS QuantThu
, SUM(0) AS QuantFri
, SUM(0) AS QuantSat
, SUM(0) AS QuantSun
, SUM(t.a3CloudTimeQuantity) AS QuantSum
, t.a3CloudTimeUserID AS tempUserID
, t.a3CloudTimeUnitID AS TimeUnitID
FROM a3CloudTime t
WHERE t.a3CloudTimeUserID = @UserID AND t.a3CloudTimeDate = @DateFrom 
AND
NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT  te.ProjID, te.ActivityID, te.TimeCodeID, te.TimeUnitID, te.QuantMon,          te.QuantTue, te.QuantWed , te.QuantThu , te.QuantFri , te.QuantSat, te.QuantSun, te.QuantSum
FROM    #tempTable te
WHERE   te.ProjID = t.a3CloudTimeProjectID AND te.ActivityID = t.a3CloudTimeActivityID AND te.TimeCodeID = t.a3CloudTimeCodeID AND te.TimeUnitID = t.a3CloudTimeUnitID
)
GROUP BY a3CloudTimeProjectID, a3CloudTimeCodeID, a3CloudTimeActivityID, a3CloudTimeUserID, a3CloudTimeUnitID



SELECT
ProjID AS HiddenColData01
, tempUserID AS HiddenColData02
, p.a3CloudProjectName AS ColData01
, a.a3CloudActivityName AS ColData02
, us.a3CloudUserName AS ColData03
, '00' + CONVERT (nvarchar(10),c.a3CloudTimeCodeNumber) + '-' +     c.a3CloudTimeCodeName AS ColData04
, QuantMon AS ColData05
, QuantTue AS ColData06
, QuantWed AS ColData07
, QuantThu AS ColData08
, QuantFri AS ColData09
, QuantSat AS ColData10
, QuantSun AS ColData11
, QuantSum AS ColData12


FROM #tempTable tt

INNER JOIN a3CloudProject p ON p.a3CloudProjectID = tt.ProjID
INNER JOIN a3CloudActivity a ON a.a3CloudActivityID = tt.ActivityID
INNER JOIN a3CloudTimeCode c ON c.a3CloudTimeCodeID = tt.TimeCodeID
INNER JOIN a3CloudTimeUnit u ON u.a3CloudTimeUnitID = tt.TimeUnitID
INNER JOIN a3CloudUser us ON us.a3CloudUserID = tt.tempUserID

GO
```

And the result will be:

```
5CF51017-2404-42B4-B12E-56B5B83B86E3    69fef3ef-10ee-4019-9e80-772261cf712a      Förvaltning   Konsult Fredrik Krantz  001-Normal  1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00    1.00
5CF51017-2404-42B4-B12E-56B5B83B86E3    69fef3ef-10ee-4019-9e80-772261cf712a    Förvaltning Konsult Fredrik Krantz  003-OB 75%  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    4.00    0.00    4.00
```

But it should be:

```
5CF51017-2404-42B4-B12E-56B5B83B86E3    69fef3ef-10ee-4019-9e80-772261cf712a      Förvaltning   Konsult Fredrik Krantz  001-Normal  1.00    3.00    5.00    5.00     0.00   0.00    0.00    14.00
5CF51017-2404-42B4-B12E-56B5B83B86E3    69fef3ef-10ee-4019-9e80-772261cf712a    Förvaltning Konsult Fredrik Krantz  003-OB 75%  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    4.00    0.00    4.00
```

The difference between the actual result and my wanted result is that the insert statement doesnt update the values (Quant) in tempTable.

Maybe i should have some IF statement, but doesnt know how i will write it in the sproc.

Comment: I know its swedish in the fields on result but these fields are not important here

Comment: The result will populate a c# table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit too specific, I look at a generilized version.

You have a table with a date, a value, and some foreign keys,
and you want to display it per week, with one column per week day.

(The exemple is made in mariadb, hope you can convert it to your sql-version)

Exemple of simplified table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE logged_time
(
    time_id SERIAL,
    user_id INT,
    project_id INT,
    type ENUM('work', 'ob'),
    log_date DATE,
    quantity FLOAT
);
```

You can solve your problem by create a view, using if-statments, like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW logged_weeks AS
SELECT
  YEAR(log_date), 
  WEEK(log_date), 
  user_id, 
  project_id, 
  type , 
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 0, quantity, 0)) AS Monday, 
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 1, quantity, 0)) AS Tuesday, 
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 2, quantity, 0)) AS Wednesday, 
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 3, quantity, 0)) AS Thursday,
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 4, quantity, 0)) AS Friday, 
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 5, quantity, 0)) AS Saturday, 
  SUM(if(weekday(log_date) = 6, quantity, 0)) AS Sunday
FROM logged_time
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(log_date), user_id, project_id, type;
```

for testing I used this testdata

```sql
INSERT INTO logged_time SELECT NULL, 1, 1, 'work', 20150921, 8;
INSERT INTO logged_time SELECT NULL, 1, 1, 'ob', 20150921, 1.5;
INSERT INTO logged_time SELECT NULL, 1, 1, 'work', 20150923, 6.5;
INSERT INTO logged_time SELECT NULL, 1, 2, 'work', 20150924, 8;
```

And running the query `SELECT * FROM logged_weeks;´ gave me this list:

```
+----------------+----------------+---------+------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
| YEAR(log_date) | WEEK(log_date) | user_id | project_id | type | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
+----------------+----------------+---------+------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|           2015 |             38 |       1 |          1 | work |      8 |       0 |       6.5 |        0 |      0 |        0 |      0 |
|           2015 |             38 |       1 |          1 | ob   |    1.5 |       0 |         0 |        0 |      0 |        0 |      0 |
|           2015 |             38 |       1 |          2 | work |      0 |       0 |         0 |        8 |      0 |        0 |      0 |
+----------------+----------------+---------+------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

If you still want to use a temporary table, you may want to studie the
`INSERT INTO ... SET ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. But I wonder if anyone can give me a better and mor clean solution.

I solved it like this:

```
CREATE PROC getweek3
@UserID nvarchar(50)
, @DateFrom datetime
AS

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
id int primary key identity(1,1)
, ProjID nvarchar(50)
, ActivityID nvarchar(50)
, TimeCodeID nvarchar(50)
, QuantMon decimal(18,2)
, QuantTue decimal(18,2)
, QuantWed decimal(18,2)
, QuantThu decimal(18,2)
, QuantFri decimal(18,2)
, QuantSat decimal(18,2)
, QuantSun decimal(18,2)
, QuantSum decimal(18,2)
, tempUserID nvarchar(50)
, TimeUnitID nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #tempTable
SELECT
t.a3CloudTimeProjectID AS ProjID
, t.a3CloudTimeActivityID AS ActivityID
, t.a3CloudTimeCodeID AS TimeCodeID
, SUM(0) AS QuantMon
, SUM(0) AS QuantTue
, SUM(0) AS QuantWed
, SUM(0) AS QuantThu
, SUM(0) AS QuantFri
, SUM(0) AS QuantSat
, SUM(0) AS QuantSun
, SUM(0) AS QuantSum
, t.a3CloudTimeUserID AS tempUserID
, t.a3CloudTimeUnitID AS TimeUnitID
FROM a3CloudTime t
WHERE t.a3CloudTimeUserID = @UserID AND t.a3CloudTimeDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND DATEADD(day,6,@DateFrom)
GROUP BY a3CloudTimeProjectID, a3CloudTimeCodeID, a3CloudTimeActivityID, a3CloudTimeUserID, a3CloudTimeUnitID

UPDATE #tempTable
SET QuantMon = t.a3CloudTimeQuantity
FROM a3CloudTime t
WHERE ProjID = t.a3CloudTimeProjectID 
AND ActivityID = t.a3CloudTimeActivityID 
AND tempUserID = t.a3CloudTimeUserID 
AND TimeUnitID = t.a3CloudTimeUnitID
AND TimeCodeID = t.a3CloudTimeCodeID
AND t.a3CloudTimeUserID = @UserID
AND t.a3CloudTimeDate = @DateFrom

SELECT
ProjID AS HiddenColData01
, tempUserID AS HiddenColData02
, p.a3CloudProjectName AS ColData01
, a.a3CloudActivityName AS ColData02
, us.a3CloudUserName AS ColData03
, '00' + CONVERT (nvarchar(10),c.a3CloudTimeCodeNumber) + '-' + c.a3CloudTimeCodeName AS ColData04
, QuantMon AS ColData05
, QuantTue AS ColData06
, QuantWed AS ColData07
, QuantThu AS ColData08
, QuantFri AS ColData09
, QuantSat AS ColData10
, QuantSun AS ColData11
, QuantSum AS ColData12


FROM #tempTable tt

INNER JOIN a3CloudProject p ON p.a3CloudProjectID = tt.ProjID
INNER JOIN a3CloudActivity a ON a.a3CloudActivityID = tt.ActivityID
INNER JOIN a3CloudTimeCode c ON c.a3CloudTimeCodeID = tt.TimeCodeID
INNER JOIN a3CloudTimeUnit u ON u.a3CloudTimeUnitID = tt.TimeUnitID
INNER JOIN a3CloudUser us ON us.a3CloudUserID = tt.tempUserID

GO
```

I running the UPDATE statement 7 times (1 for each day).

A lot of code, can i make it with less code? And more effective?